# extending controllers with raw js files in sailjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm using "sails": "~0.10.5" and I'm making a controller / webservice that takes get and post.  Everything's fine, but I want to bring in a couple of js files I'd written earlier for processing uploaded csv's.  I created a src folder on the root of my sails.js project that require a few modules, etc.  I'm wondering is this the "sails.js way" of adding util / helper files?

Should I go through the extra steps of making them an npm module or is that overkill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is :

Those file/library have to be added in `api/services/` folder and be "ES6 modules"

for example create a file `api/services/Hello.js`

```
// say hello
module.exports = {

    hello: function(name){
      sails.log.warn("Hello was called !"); //not a good log ...  
      return "hello" + name + sails.config.local.helloconf; //you can then access configs and some other sails native functions;
    }
};
```

in your controller you can then simply do something like `Hello.hello("bob");`

Comment: nice, thanks.  Adding this for future reference. https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/concepts/Services/Services.md